# How to express the surface $ \ y^{2}+z^{2}=15 \ $ between $x=-6$ and $x=8$ in parametric form?

Tags: parametric

**How to express the surface $ \ y^{2}+z^{2}=15 \  $ between    $x=-6$  and  $x=8$  in parametric form?**

From $ y^{2}+z^{2}=15 $ , we can have $$ y=\sqrt {15} \cos t  \quad  \text{ and }\quad z=\sqrt{15} \sin t,$$ but how to manage $x=-6$ to $x=8$?  Is it like $-6 \leq x \leq 8$? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Those bounds on $y$ make very little sense, as both of them are impossible to achieve on the surface you're describing, do you mean those to be bounds on $x$?

Comment: ok , there was a typo, but now i have made correction

Comment: so what is x? So you mean y or z?

Comment: please now see the full correction of the question

Comment: You can just write x=-6+u with u ranging from 0 to 14, no?

Answer (score 1):

Your surface is a cylinder symmetric about the $x$-axis. You need two parameters  for a 2-dimensional surface. A "natural" choice of the two parameters would be

(1) the $x$ coordinate (this brings you down to a circle), $x\in[-6,8]$, and

(2) the angle $\theta$ (or $t$ if you prefer) specifying a point on the circle and ranging from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Your attempted solution seems right on. Every point on the surface can be written as
$$
(x,y,z) = (x,\sqrt{15}\cos\theta,\sqrt{15}\sin\theta).
$$

If necessary, we can bring the parameters into the range $0$ to $1$ using a linear transformation; but your problem statement does not specifically ask you to have parameters in the $[0,1]$ range (or does it?)